# LVM: Move physical volumes between disks while other physical volumes are missing

Tags: linux, hard-drive, lvm

I have a single volume group (VG) that consists of several physical volumes (PV) distributed over various disks. Now I want to move all PVs that reside on a disk A to a new disk B. However, since I don't have enough slots to just add disk B, I have to temporarily remove a third disk C (which also contains PVs pertaining to the same VG) for the duration of the operation. Afterwards, when disk A is no longer necessary, there will be space again for disk C.

Now my question: Is the fact of the missing disk C going to affect the moving of PVs from disk A to disk B?

Of course, I could just try it in a dry-run with a bunch of loop-back devices. But even if it works for the dry-run, I wouldn't be sure that it is actually *specified* to work (and therefore won't cause data loss with the real data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If LVs on disk C are ONLY on disk C, you could [vgsplit(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/vgsplit.8.html) the disk C into a new VG and then remove the disk C, do what you need (likely [pvmove(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pvmove.8.html)), and then [vgmerge(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/vgmerge.8.html):

```
vgsplit existingVG newVG PV
# ...do what you need here...
vgmerge existingVG newVG
```

If LVs are on disk C and other disk you would get partial LVs after removing the disk C, and though LVM does allow activating partial devices with `--partial` option, but it does not allow changing such VG (You would need to run `vgreduce --removemissing VG` but that's NOT what you want.)

You could do it offline using dd: boot a live CD and run `dd if=/dev/OLDPV of=/dev/NEWPV bs=1M`. You may need to resize partitions afterwards, which is not straightforward. But at least you have a "backup" (unless you switch the arguments to dd, of course)

Comment: Thanks. Interesting idea doing it using `dd`, I will think about that.